# Python Mapping over City

Tags: python, mapping

I am working with a python Dataframe the information that is needed to solve this problem revolves around three specific columns being: latitude, longitude, and a prediction (0,1,2). The prediction values are either 0, 1, or 2 and I would like to represent all of these points on a map namely the city of Miami. The catch is that I would like for the prediction values of 0,1,2 to map to three distinct colors on an actual map. Does anyone have any idea how I would be able to do this in python?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could use GeoPandas, using a shape file for Miami. With this you will be able to get the map, then color it using Matplotlib.

Comment: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Markers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping with Dataframe Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416216/mapping-with-dataframe-python)