# Mapping with Dataframe Python

Tags: python, dataframe, mapping

I have a DataFrame in python with three columns latitude, longitude, and color (3 different colors represented by the numbers 0, 1, and 2). How can I plot these values onto a map with the coordinates associated color?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Markers

Comment: https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps